# Segmentation fault in 2-d Array

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

I was working on this problem:

```
Coding Problem
Problem Statement: Edit Distance
Problem Level: MEDIUM
Problem Description:
You are given two strings S and T of lengths M and N, respectively. Find the 'Edit Distance' between the strings.
Edit Distance of two strings is the minimum number of steps required to make one string equal to the other. In order to do so, you can perform the following three operations:
1. Delete a character
2. Replace a character with another one
3. Insert a character

Note :
Strings don't contain spaces in between.

Input format :
The first line of input contains the string S of length M.

The second line of the input contains the String T of length N.

Output format :
Print the minimum 'Edit Distance' between the strings.

Constraints :
0 <= M <= 10 ^ 3
0 <= N <= 10 ^ 3

Time Limit: 1 sec

Sample Input 1 :
abc
dc

Sample Output 1 :
2

Explanation to the Sample Input 1 :
 In 2 operations we can make string T to look like string S.
First, insert character 'a' to string T, which makes it "adc".

And secondly, replace the character 'd' of string T with 'b' from the string S. This would make string T as "abc" which is also string S.

Hence, the minimum distance.

Sample Input 2 :
whgtdwhgtdg
aswcfg

Sample Output 2 :
9
```

I wrote the following code for this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int EditDistance(string s, string t, int **arr)
{
    int i = s.size();
    int j = t.size();
    //Base Case
    if (t.size() == 0 || s.size()==0)
    {
        return max (s.size(),t.size());
    }
    int x, y, z, min_num;
    if (arr[i][j] != (-1))
    {
        return arr[i][j];
    }
    //Recursive Case
    if (s[0] == t[0])
    {
        arr[i][j] = EditDistance(s.substr(1), t.substr(1), arr);
        return arr[i][j];
    }
    else
    {
        x = 1 + EditDistance(s.substr(1), t, arr);
        y = 1 + EditDistance(s, t.substr(1), arr);
        z = 1 + EditDistance(s.substr(1), t.substr(1), arr);
        min_num = min(x, min(y, z));
        arr[i][j] = min_num;
    }
    return min_num;
}
int EditDistance(string s, string t)
{
    int a = s.size() + 1; //rows
    int b = t.size() + 1; //columns
    int **arr = new int *[b];
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[a];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {   cout << "Value of i is " << i <<endl;
            cout << "Value of j is " << j <<endl;
            arr[i][j] = (-1);
            cout << "Value of array is " << arr[i][j] <<endl;
        }
    }
    return EditDistance(s, t, arr);
    delete[]arr;
}
int main()
{
    string s1, s2;
    cout << "Enter the two strings" << endl;
    cin >> s1 >> s2;
    cout << EditDistance(s1, s2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I tried to enter "abc" and "ab" as the strings, it gives segmentation fault at i=3 and j=0 at the line `arr[i][j] = (-1)` in the function `int EditDistance(string s, string t)`. However, what I really couldn't get was that why am I receving a segmentation fault, when I have created a 2-d array of size 4*3, then accessing the element arr[3][0] shouldn't give me a segmentation fault. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not the problem but probably wrong - `if (t.size() == 0 || t.size()==0)` . Also good practice `int x, y, z, min_num;` if you can't initialise variables you should probably delay their declaration until you can.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, however that's not the problem @RichardCritten

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for your suggestions, but could you please come to the question I asked?

Comment: `int **arr = new int *[b];` prefer `std::vector< std::vector< int > > arr;` try to never use c-arrays.

Comment: Am reading your code - it's hardly a [mcve] - shortest correct answer is _"user a debugger"_ and find it yourself this is not a paid service.

Comment: @RichardCritten Why shouldn't I use C-arrays? I have solved many other questions also by using 2-D arrays (C-arrays), they were working correctly.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have described my problem in great detail. Don't go by the length of the code, I have told you about the function also in which the error is there.

Comment: Your program leaks memory. It also contains a bug that is hard to debug. It is almost impossible to make `std::vector` leak memory, and it is relatively easy to debug when a bug does occur.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem Can you explain clearly?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the Levenshtein distance . . .

There is one semantic error. Otherwise the program is OK.

Then you do many style erros. And you are using `new` and raw pointers for owned memory. In C++ such raw pointers are considered as evil and should not be used. Under no circumstances.

Additionally you forgot the release the owned memory. Your `delete` statement is an unreachable code area. And it only deletes one dimension.

If you would use meaningful variable names, then you would see immediately your problem. See here.

```
 int numberOfRows = s.size() + 1; //rows
    int numberOfColumns = t.size() + 1; //columns

    int **arr = new int *[numberOfColumns];
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++)
    {
        arr[columnIndex] = new int[numberOfRows];
    }

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++)
        {   cout << "Value of i is " << rowIndex << endl;
            cout << "Value of j is " << columnIndex << endl;
            arr[rowIndex][j] = (-1);
            cout << "Value of array is " << arr[rowIndex][columnIndex] <<endl;
        }
    }
```

You are simply mixing up rows and columns. The indices are twisted.

Correcting that and switching the language to C++, will give you the following, basically identical code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


int EditDistanceRecursive(const std::string& stringLeft, const std::string& stringRight, int** arr)
{
    size_t sizeOfStringLeft = stringLeft.size();
    size_t sizeOfStringRight = stringRight.size();

    //Base Case
    if (stringLeft.empty() || stringRight.empty())
    {
        return std::max(stringLeft.size(), stringRight.size());
    }

    int x, y, z, min_num;
    if (arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight] != (-1))
    {
        return arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight];
    }

    //Recursive Case
    if (stringLeft[0] == stringRight[0])
    {
        arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight] = EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft.substr(1), stringRight.substr(1), arr);
        return arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight];
    }
    else
    {
        x = 1 + EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft.substr(1), stringRight, arr);
        y = 1 + EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft, stringRight.substr(1), arr);
        z = 1 + EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft.substr(1), stringRight.substr(1), arr);
        min_num = std::min(x, std::min(y, z));
        arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight] = min_num;
    }
    return min_num;
}
int EditDistance(const std::string& stringLeft, const std::string& stringRight)
{
    // Get the dimensions of the dp table
    size_t numberOfRows = stringLeft.size() + 1; //rows
    size_t numberOfColumns = stringRight.size() + 1; //columns

    // Dynamically allocate 2d-array in old C-Style
    int** arr = new int* [numberOfRows];
    for (size_t  rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        arr[rowIndex] = new int[numberOfColumns];
    }

    // Initialize memory and show debug output
    for (size_t  rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (size_t  columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++)
        {
            std::cout << "Value of row is " << rowIndex << '\n';
            std::cout << "Value of column is " << columnIndex << '\n';
            arr[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (-1);
            std::cout << "Value of array at row/column is " << arr[rowIndex][columnIndex] << '\n';
        }
    }
    // Caluclate result
    int result = EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft, stringRight, arr);

    // Release dynamic allocated memory 
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++)
        delete [] arr[rowIndex];
    delete [] arr;

    // Inform Result to upper function
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    // Tell user what to do
    std::cout << "Enter the two strings:\n";

    // Get 2 strings
    std::string stringLeft, stringRight;
    std::cin >> stringLeft >> stringRight;

    // Calculate and output distance
    int result = EditDistance(stringLeft, stringRight);

    std::cout << "\n\nResult. Distance is: " << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

- I used meaningful variable names
- Fixed minor semantic bugs
- Made some minor style optimizations
- Use fully qualified names everywhere

And if we get rid of C-Style, not at all recommended `new` and raw pointers, we get the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using Columns = std::vector<int>;
using Arr = std::vector<Columns>;

int EditDistanceRecursive(const std::string& stringLeft, const std::string& stringRight, Arr& arr)
{
    size_t sizeOfStringLeft = stringLeft.size();
    size_t sizeOfStringRight = stringRight.size();

    //Base Case
    if (stringLeft.empty() || stringRight.empty())
    {
        return std::max(stringLeft.size(), stringRight.size());
    }

    int x, y, z, min_num;
    if (arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight] != (-1))
    {
        return arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight];
    }

    //Recursive Case
    if (stringLeft[0] == stringRight[0])
    {
        arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight] = EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft.substr(1), stringRight.substr(1), arr);
        return arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight];
    }
    else
    {
        x = 1 + EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft.substr(1), stringRight, arr);
        y = 1 + EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft, stringRight.substr(1), arr);
        z = 1 + EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft.substr(1), stringRight.substr(1), arr);
        min_num = std::min(x, std::min(y, z));
        arr[sizeOfStringLeft][sizeOfStringRight] = min_num;
    }
    return min_num;
}
int EditDistance(const std::string& stringLeft, const std::string& stringRight)
{
    // Get the dimensions of the dp table
    size_t numberOfRows = stringLeft.size() + 1; //rows
    size_t numberOfColumns = stringRight.size() + 1; //columns

    // Create and initialize 2d vector
    Arr arr(numberOfRows, Columns(numberOfColumns, -1));

    // Caluclate result
    return  EditDistanceRecursive(stringLeft, stringRight, arr);
}
int main()
{
    // Tell user what to do
    std::cout << "Enter the two strings:\n";

    // Get 2 strings
    std::string stringLeft, stringRight;
    std::cin >> stringLeft >> stringRight;

    // Calculate and output distance
    int result = EditDistance(stringLeft, stringRight);

    std::cout << "\n\nResult. Distance is: " << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

What a pity that nobody will read that . . .

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you inverted the indices of the array subscripts. You create the array like [b][a], but then use it like it's [a][b].